# id no Increment correctly

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have table has some columns , one of them called `student_id` has auto Increment and primary key .

but my problem when i added any values to it from another table it automatically generate some ids

for more clear : my field `student_id` has values  1 2 3 4 5

but when i added to it new values it start from 15 and 16 and so on .

is there is any cache or something like that ?

I'm using :

```
 INSERT INTO student(first_name,school_id,class_id,stage_id,grade_id)
 SELECT first_name, 1,1,1,1 FROM `TABLE 13`
```

Table 13 has :

> first_name (varchar)

`student` has :

> student_id (INT) primary key AUTOIncrement

Comment: Show table definitions for `Table 13` and `student`.

Comment: describe the table :)
DESCRIBE `table 13`

Comment: Did you perform some inserts and drops from student after it had student_id 5 (and before adding your new values)?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Comment: yes i have done some work with it , i want to clear all cache

Comment: @Mihai  i have delete all values in student and try to add to it again but student id start from 120 not from 1

Comment: as Mihai and others have mentioned, deleted values and alter table. But this defeats the whole purpose of auto_increment if you do not start from scratch (i.e start over from empty table).

Comment: @user2884425 if you want to remove the data and reset the id use TRUNCATE not delete or drop.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL always auto-increments from the highest value that field has ever had in it, even if that record was deleted or altered. If you want the IDs to start over from 1, use this command (as @mihai said in the comments):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Also think about why you want your IDs to start from 1. Are you writing your software to rely on all IDs being consecutive and starting from 1? That's a bad idea -- what if a student drops out later?

Comment: This is correct, but since the original question is tagged with phpMyAdmin there's a nice graphical way to do it as well: from the Operations tab look for the AUTO_INCREMENT field and change the number there. Also, I agree that you probably don't really want to change the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

try this....if it fit's to your problem and don't forget to checked it.....

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
    `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `school_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `class_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `stage_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `grade_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`school_id`)
)
```